# Bind contextmenu with dynamic elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic, binding, contextmenu

I'm working on a script to create a custom right-click menu when you click on images inside a contenteditable div. This is the part that does it:

```
$('.editor-text img').bind('contextmenu', function (event) {
   // Do stuff
});
```

This works on elements already there. But if you move one of the images, thereby making it a newly added dynamic element, jquery can no longer find it. I thought the solution should be this:

```
$(document).on("contextmenu", ".editor-text img", function (event) {
   // Do stuff
});
```

But this doesn't work either. How can I adjust the code so it will work with dynamic elements?

**To see the problem:**

1. Go here: http://jsfiddle.net/YsW8D/4/ using a webkit browser
2. Right Click an image to see the menu
3. After closing the menu, click and drag the image somewhere else in the text
4. Right clicking again will not work.
5. Line 9 of the js is the related code.

Comment: On firefox I don't even get the first context menu, fyi.

Comment: Remove `return false;` from first img contextmenu handler, this makes event to stop propagate to document level, then you can delegate event: http://jsfiddle.net/YsW8D/5/  BTW, looks like you would have better to clone element with bound handlers instead using `.clone(true)`, would keep logic more readable imho

Comment: For first handler, instead maybe use `event.preventDefault();` if it was what you needed instead

Comment: artm- Thanks for the firefox report. I'll look into it although this is made for a webkit environment. A. Wolff- thank you. I've got it working now with your help. If you want to post as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

first step: prevent default.
second step: set the position to mouse pointer.
third step: show the menu.

(check the example below.)

```js
function openMenu(e) {
var h1 = document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0];
var menu = document.getElementById("menu");
e.preventDefault();
menu.style.left = e.pageX + "px";
menu.style.top = e.pageY + "px";
menu.style.display = "block";
document.addEventListener("click", function() {
menu.style.display = "none";
});
}
```

```css
body {
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
}

#menu {
position: absolute;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
background-color: white;
}

#menu a {
height: 50px;
border: 1px solid black;
cursor: pointer;
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
}

#menu a:hover {
background-color: #D3D3D3;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h1 oncontextmenu="openMenu(event)">Right click on me.</h1>
<div id="menu" style="display: none;">
<a href="https://www.google.com/" target="_black">Google</a>
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com/" target="_black">Stackoverflow</a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```